# How is $G_0 = f(t \pm r/c)/r$ a solution to Poisson's Equation For A Point Source?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, greens-functions

In his 1972 book, "The Classical Electromagnetic Field", on p.184, Leonard Eyges States,
[image]

I don't see how Equation (11.41) is a solution to (11.40)

Comment: 1: don't just use an image - it makes the search not work well. 2: That's not Poisson's equation, that's the wave equation. If you just do the partial derivatives and plug them in to the equation, and you do it right, you'll see it works.

Comment: Is this more suitable for math stack exchange?